# Creating new column with pieces of 3 columns

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I would like to create a new column in a dataframe containing pieces of 3 different columns.I would like the first 5 letters of the last name, after removing non alphabeticals, if it is that long else just the last name, the first 2 letters of the first name and a code appended to the end.

The code below doesnt work but thats where I am and it isnt close to working

```
df['namecode'] = df.Last.str.replace('[^a-zA-Z]', '')[:5]+df.First.str.replace('[^a-zA-Z]', '')[:2]+str(jr['code'])



Name  lastname  code   namecode

jeff White 0989 Whiteje0989

Zach Bunt 0798  Buntza0798

ken Black 5764  Blackke5764
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach.

Use pandas [`str.slice`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.Series.str.slice.html) instead of trying to do string indexing.

For example:

import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'First': ['jeff', 'zach', 'ken'],
        'Last': ['White^', 'Bun/t', 'Bl?ack'],
        'code': ['0989', '0798', '5764']
    }
)
print(df['Last'].str.replace('[^a-zA-Z]', '').str.slice(0,5)
      + df['First'].str.slice(0,2) + df['code'])
#0    Whiteje0989
#1     Buntza0798
#2    Blackke5764
#dtype: object
```

Comment: Didnt seem to work with the dataframe I am loading in but I recreated from the dictionary above and your way worked. Dont know the problem. Here is the error                                                                    
         TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21')

Comment: It's hard to tell for sure, but maybe it would be as simple as converting the `code` column to string: `... + df['code'].astype(str)`? Can you edit your question to add the `dtypes` of your columns?